# how to style an individual page in a category

Tags: posts, categories, pages, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show a post single post in page template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59599/how-to-show-a-post-single-post-in-page-template)

im trying to understand how to target a template for an individual post.

if i use the following hierarchy for my site,

```
homepage
services
    - track car
    - race car
    - road car
    - fast road
    - paddock services
about
contact
```

what i really want to do is create and style the template for the post i've created for "track car" which is a post belonging to category "services".

I've worked out that if i create category-services.php then i can style an overview page which covers all of the services on one page, but what template do i create if i want to style a page which will show the service requested.

what template will cover the following requests 
     "somewebsite.com/services/track-car/"
     "somewebsite.com/services/race-car/"

Comment: i've just had it suggested to me to think of the services tree as the blog, which makes the categories a type of post. i guess then that i could use an if statement in the usual pages (index and archive.php?). is this the way forwards?

Comment: See [this Q/A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59599/how-to-show-a-post-single-post-in-page-template).

Comment: kaiser, that was exactly what i needed to read. if you want to re-add it as an answer i'll accept it. unless thats against the rules?

Comment: n/p - I marked it as duplicate. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can be done with posts, but if you're using pages, you can use a template called `page-id.php` where `id` is the page id of your `track car` page. The [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) can help you.