# How to show a post single post in page template

Tags: page-template, homepage, single

Currently I've divided posts into 5 different categories, based on the categories I've created 5 page templates. all of the pages are listed into the home page navigation menu. in my home page I'm showing 5 posts in five different categories. when they clicked a post that post will shown in the single page template(that's what word press normally does) but i want to show that post into my page template. because each page template having different designs. if there is any way to set the permalink  to point to the page template and show the post in to full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [»Template Hierarchy«](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) doesn't allow this per default.

Inside your `single.php` template, you can call [`load_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_template).

This will allow you to simply include the template you need, based on the [`in_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) conditional tag.

```
// inside single.php
if ( in_category( 'foo' ) )
{
    load_template( get_stylesheet_directory().'foo_template.php' );
} 
elseif ( in_category( 'bar' ) )
{
    load_template( get_stylesheet_directory().'bar_template.php' );
} 
elseif ( in_category( 'whatever' ) )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: its working fine. You saved me lot of time. thanks